# Updating UI from listener - textview not getting updated

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to update UI of a textview, progressbar and buttons inside a listener. Following is my code:

```
    GetDownloadListener listener=new GetDownloadListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDownloaded(String path, int pos) {
        //updating db 
        System.out.println("On downloaded"+contentCosts.get(pos).getRecoContentName());
        updateDatabase(pos,path);
        mainProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
                mainProgress.setMax(contentCosts.size());
                textViewContent.setText("Downloaded "+contentCosts.get(pos).getRecoContentName());// This textview does not get updated
        downloadedList.add(contentCosts.get(pos));
        downloadCount++;
        mainProgress.setProgress(downloadCount);
        if(downloadCount<contentCosts.size()){
            callDownload(downloadCount);
        }else{
            DownloadingScreen.enableLaunchButton();
        }
    }
};
```

progressbar and buttons get updated based on the code inside the listener, but the line `textViewContent.setText("Downloaded "+contentCosts.get(pos).getRecoContentName());` does not update the textview. What can be the reason why this textview alone does not get updated where as the other UI components get updated from the same listener.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: does it show nothing or does it crash?

Comment: it does not update the UI which is "Downloading" to "Downloaded"+contentCosts.... The code does not crash

Comment: any exceptions or errors in logcat?

Comment: no exceptions or errors in logcat